# PHP mb_substr not working correctly

Tags: php, html

I am using Notepad++ to do some HTML and PHP. At one point, I have the following code:

```
$strUserEmail = $_SESSION["userLoggedIn"];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Email = '$strUserEmail'";
$rsUser = mysql_query($strSQL)
    or die($db_name . " : " . $strSQL . " : " . mysql_error());

$rowUser = mysql_fetch_array($rsUser);

$strUserName = $rowUser["FirstName"] . '.' . mb_substr($rowUser["LastName"], 0);
```

What should come out of that is, for instance, Tom S (Tom being the first name, and S being the first letter of the last name). However, it simply gives me the full last name.

As a second issue, I am using $strUserName to seed a text box in a form following this, but whenever a space is encountered, is ignores the rest as some sort of delimiting value.

Comment: A good place for examples if to look at the non mb_ function: http://www.php.net/substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve that by using substring method.

```
$strUserName = $rowUser["FirstName"] . ' ' . substr($rowUser["LastName"], 0, 1); 

echo $strUserName;
```

Edit. Thanks to @ czachor making me notice about this.

If you working with unicode charachters, the above function may not work perfectly for you, because the substr() function is not mutli-byte aware. For instance if you are in German, there are umlauts, like Ä,ö ß and so son. So you can better use  the `mb_substr()` like the following.

```
 $strUserName1 = $rowUser["FirstName"]. ' ' . mb_substr($rowUser["ÖLastName"], 0, 1,'UTF-8');

echo utf8_decode($strUserName1);
```

Comment: I think it isn't the good answer. What if `LastName` starts with letter `Ż`, `Ü` etc? `Substr()` won't handle it properly, you should use `mb_substr()`.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit: @Mubo, @user3169698: check my comment above. And there is incorrect use of single quotes, should be: `substr($rowUser["LastName"], 0, 1);`.

Comment: You were right  and i have edited the answer accordingly thanks. #

Answer (score 2):

You ommited `length` param in `mb_substr()` function. [Read the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions any more as they are deprecated and very unsafe, please learn & use mysqli_* : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Secondly, you have to supply a length to mb_substr, passing the default `Null` will be interpreted as 0.

try:
`$strUserName = $rowUser["FirstName"] . '.' . mb_substr($rowUser["LastName"], 0, 1);`